# Install package svg.sty

Tags: graphics, packages, svg

I am using Kile to write latex documents. I want to include .svg picture in my document. After including

```
\usepackage{svg}
```

and compiling my document into pdf, I have an error:

```
"File 'svg.sty' not found. \usepackage "
```

So I downloaded package svg from ftp.tex.ac.uk but I don't know how to install it.
I tried to use package manager, but it didn't see this as a package. 
Can someone suggest me how can I do that?

Comment: the package is part of TeXLive and MikTeX the reason why it should be installable by the package manager

Comment: Depends on the version of TeX Live, at least. TL 2011 didn't include it. But there's not enough information to say whether that's the case here.

Comment: @cfr I have TexLive installed, version 2012. But when I want to include \usepackage{svg} I have the same error like I posted.

Comment: What do kpsewhich svg.sty and locate svg.sty give? (Only run locate on non-Windows probably.)

Comment: It gives no results, what is strange, because I installed all Tex Live packages, not only basic, but also the full one

Comment: Perhaps it was part of an update i.e. not included in the initial installation. (It was not in TL 2011 and the file date in the TL 2012 version is 2012/09/05.) If you don't wish to update to TL 2013, the easiest option is to put it in your personal texmf tree. You can get the location with kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME. Then create sub-directories there tex/latex/svg and put svg.sty inside so you have ${TEXMFHOME}/tex/latex/svg/svg.sty (adjust for Windows). [Obviously open the package to get svg.sty out first.]