# Install new package `svg.sty' ubuntu

Tags: packages, installing, texstudio, ubuntu, svg

I use `texstudio` in Ubuntu and I would like to use svg package:

```
\usepackage{svg}
```

> File `svg.sty' not found. ^^M

The only thing I found is a [closed thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150616/install-package-svg-sty).

My attempt for installation of this package has failed:

```
$ tlmgr install svg
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/ar2015/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.
```

Where am I wrong?

**Update**

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includesvg[width=140mm]{images/pos_before.svg}
\caption{Previous output \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
```

---

Please avoid linking to posts which do not solve the problem straight forward.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The best thing to do is to figure out in which package Debian puts the package `svg`. That is, Debian will put a bunch of related LaTeX packages into one Debian package. Find out which one and install that using your regular package manager (not `tlmgr`). That is, if you wish to use Debian's packages for TeX Live, stick to them.

Comment: The `svg` CTAN package is part of your distribution's `texlive-latex-extra` package. Install that (`texlive-latex-extra`) with your distribution's package manager.

Comment: @PaulGessler texlive-latex-extra is 558 MB so I used `--no-install-recommends` switch to reduce it into 48 MB. Now there is no error on latex package calling but I see this problem `Unknown graphics extension: .svg. ...raphics[width=140mm]{images/pos_after.svg}`

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `svg` package? You should not use `\includegraphics` but `\includesvg[<options>]{<svg filename>}` instead, for SVG files.

Comment: @PaulGessler I think it looks for a .pdf_tex file.

Comment: I will ask again (sorry): did you read the documentation? Omit the SVG file's extension. Do you compile with the `-shell-escape` flag? Do you have InkScape installed? These are all things that are needed for the package `svg` to do what it does.

Comment: @PaulGessler I didnt read any SVG documentation. I just followed [this URL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package). Even dropping SVG file extention did not help. I use TexStudio. I have not heard about `-shell-escape`

Comment: @PaulGessler I had seen that post. It did not solve my problem.

Comment: @ar2015 the solution at that post (use `apt-get` to install the appropriate distro package) is _precisely_ what you have done in your answer below, so it _did_ solve your problem.

Comment: @PaulGessler I know that I should install the related package but is `texlive-latex-extra` mentioned there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved according to the suggestion of Paul Gessler

I just added `--no-install-recommends` to reduce the size of the installed Ubuntu package:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install  texlive-latex-extra
```